# How to fix: 'After the event has been completed, the next insert set the timestamp to 0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql

I'm creating an application that records the working hours of employees.

I want all employees who have forgotten to check out from the system, set their check out time to their check in time, so they have to contact the system administrator to set their check out time manually.
Specifically I have a problem with MYSQL scheduling events.

My table look like:

`record_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`account_id` int(10) NOT NULL,

`creted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`status` enum('IN','OUT')

When i execute insert:

INSERT INTO record (account_id) VALUES(498056908)

Trigger check if record with that id already exist and set status 'IN' or 'OUT'.

Trigger look like:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `evrz`.`record_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE

INSERT ON `record` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET @lastStatus = (SELECT record.status

FROM record

where record.account_id = NEW.account_id

ORDER BY creted_at DESC LIMIT 1);

IF @lastStatus = 'OUT' OR  @lastStatus  IS NULL

then

```
set NEW.status = 'IN';
```

ELSE

```
set NEW.status = 'OUT';
```

END IF;

END

This works perfectly.

But i create event that look like:

CREATE EVENT e_daily

```
ON SCHEDULE

  EVERY 1 day

DO

    INSERT INTO record (account_id, created_at) 

    SELECT account_id, created_at

    FROM 

        record

    WHERE created_at IN 

    (SELECT max(created_at) FROM record GROUP BY account_id) 

    AND status='IN'
```

The first problem is:

Event did not get check in time to set as check out time 
instead of that event set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

The second problem is:

The next normal insertion does not execute default(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) instead of that set time like 0000-00-00 00:00:00;

After that i got this:

record_id, account_id, creted_at, status

'35', '795387614', '2019-06-17 21:11:28', 'IN'

'36', '795387614', '2019-06-17 21:15:21', 'OUT'

'37', '795387614', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'IN'

I expect the first insertion to set the current time and status 'IN', that work. And then the event finds all those who have not check out and set their time at the time of check in.You must keep in mind that an employee can log in and log out of the system several times.

Comment: instead of using `0000-00-00 00:00:00` your better off allowing `NULL` in your table..

Comment: Thanks but i do not want to have either null nor 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  for providing example data so we get a better feeling for the data and for providing a expected result so we can verify our query/solution

Comment: And format the question better as it not really formatted correct.